# Is it possible to exclude field-sets in AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, java-11

Is it possible to exclude fiel-sets in AspectJ pointcuts, so instrumentation does not stumble over final fields in Java 11?

When weaving the following aspect (the full example is here: https://github.com/DaGeRe/aspect-final-example):

```
@Pointcut("!within(de.aspectjtest..*)")
public void notWithinAspect() {
}

@Pointcut("!set(private * *)")
public void noSet() {
    
}

@Around("notWithinAspect() && noSet()")
public Object aroundStuff(final ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, final EnclosingStaticPart thisEnclosingJoinPoint)
        throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("=== Call: " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature() + " " + thisJoinPoint.getKind());
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation() + " " + thisJoinPoint.getStaticPart());
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.toLongString());
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
}
```

into

```
class FinalFieldConstructorExample {
    private final Integer parameters = 5;
    public Integer getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }
}

public class MainWithError {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinalFieldConstructorExample example = new FinalFieldConstructorExample();
        System.out.println(example.getParameters());
    }
}
```

by `java -cp target/test-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -javaagent:../aspect/target/aspectjtest-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar de.test.MainWithError` I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Update to non-static final field de.test.FinalFieldConstructorExample.parameters attempted from a different method (init$_aroundBody2) than the initialize
r method <init>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        at de.test.FinalFieldConstructorExample.init$_aroundBody2(MainWithError.java:5)                                                                                                                            
        at de.test.FinalFieldConstructorExample$AjcClosure3.run(MainWithError.java:1)                                                                                                                              
        at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:167)                                                                                                                               
        at de.aspectjtest.ExampleAspect.aroundStuff(ExampleAspect.java:27)                                                                                                                                         
        at de.test.FinalFieldConstructorExample.<init>(MainWithError.java:3)                                                                                                                                       
        at de.test.MainWithError.init$_aroundBody2(MainWithError.java:15)                                                                                                                                          
        at de.test.MainWithError$AjcClosure3.run(MainWithError.java:1)                                                                                                                                             
        at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:167)                     
        at de.aspectjtest.ExampleAspect.aroundStuff(ExampleAspect.java:27)                                                                                                                                         
        at de.test.MainWithError.main_aroundBody10(MainWithError.java)        
        at de.test.MainWithError$AjcClosure11.run(MainWithError.java:1)                                                                                                                                            
        at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:167)                     
        at de.aspectjtest.ExampleAspect.aroundStuff(ExampleAspect.java:27)     
        at de.test.MainWithError.main(MainWithError.java:15)
```

when I execute it with OpenJDK 11 (when setting everything to Java 8, it works fine). When removing the final modifier from `FinalFieldConstructorExample` and the `&& noSet()` from the pointcut, it works fine and the output contains

```
=== Call: Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int) method-call
MainWithoutError.java:5 call(Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int))
call(public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int))
=== Call: Integer de.test.NonFinalFieldConstructorExample.parameters field-set
MainWithoutError.java:5 set(Integer de.test.NonFinalFieldConstructorExample.parameters)
set(private java.lang.Integer de.test.NonFinalFieldConstructorExample.parameters)
```

Therefore, I suppose the set-call (having a `getKind` of `field-set`, which seems not to be present in OpenJDK 8) to a static field is the reason of the problem. Is there any way of excluding it from AspectJ instrumentation (or working around the problem)? The documentation (https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#primitive-pointcuts) states that get can be used in a Pointcut, but I did not find a way to specify `final`, and even if I add `noSet`, it seems to be somehow touched and the error appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are hitting [AspectJ issue #563709](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563709). The error message is the same and so is the fact that it works on Java 8 but not 11 (probably 9+).

So as a workaround for now you want to avoid around-advising constructors. Either you exclude them via

```java
@Around("notWithinAspect() && noSet() && !(execution(*.new(..)))")
```

or, considering the fact that your advice only does something before `proceed()`, just change the advice type:

```java
@Before("notWithinAspect() && noSet()")
public void beforeStuff(final JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, final EnclosingStaticPart thisEnclosingJoinPoint) {
  System.out.println("=== Call: " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature() + " " + thisJoinPoint.getKind());
  System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation() + " " + thisJoinPoint.getStaticPart());
  System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.toLongString());
}
```

If for whatever reason you need `@Around` and cannot refactor it into a `@Before` + `@After` pair generally, you can keep it with the above exclusion of constructor executions and add a separate `@Before` + `@After` advice pair just for the constructors.

---

**Update:**

> Excluding constructors or using only `@Before` works, but is not usable for my use case (method execution duration monitoring)

Well, then how about this workaround, globally replacing `@Around` by pairs of `@Before` + `@After`? You may even notice that your log now also shows additional `preinitialization` and `initialization` pointcuts which formerly were not captured by the around advice because for those pointcut types around is not supported. Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class FinalFieldConstructorExample {
  private final Integer parameters = 5;

  public Integer getParameters() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    return parameters;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class MainWithError {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FinalFieldConstructorExample example = new FinalFieldConstructorExample();
    System.out.println(example.getParameters());
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.Stack;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  private ThreadLocal<Stack<Long>> startTimeTL = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new Stack<>());

  @Pointcut("within(de.scrum_master.aspect..*)")
  public void withinAspect() {}

  @Before("!withinAspect()")
  public void beforeStuff(final JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    startTimeTL.get().push(System.currentTimeMillis());
  }

  @After("!withinAspect()")
  public void afterStuff(final JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeTL.get().pop()));
  }
}
```

The console log would look like this:

```
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.MainWithError.<clinit>) -> 1
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample.<clinit>) -> 0
preinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample()) -> 0
call(Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int)) -> 0
set(Integer de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample.parameters) -> 0
execution(de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample()) -> 1
initialization(de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample()) -> 1
call(de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample()) -> 2
get(PrintStream java.lang.System.out) -> 0
call(void java.lang.Thread.sleep(long)) -> 100
get(Integer de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample.parameters) -> 0
execution(Integer de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample.getParameters()) -> 100
call(Integer de.scrum_master.app.FinalFieldConstructorExample.getParameters()) -> 100
5
call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(Object)) -> 1
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MainWithError.main(String[])) -> 103
```

P.S.: Are you aware of the fact that for woven methods and constructors you are logging both `call` and `execution` for the same method/constructor?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Excluding constructors or using only `@Before` works, but is not usable for my use case (method execution duration monitoring). I tried excluding the field-set from monitoring (https://github.com/DaGeRe/org.aspectj/commit/da9a5aa6f3a50e2f8d181e013ac9706ca912b1b4), but the constructor execution realy causes the problem. I'll answer in the issue in more detail.

Comment: Please note my update with a workaround [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for the AspectJ issue discussion, I am going to answer on Bugzilla.